# name from Orange is not defined

Tags: python-2.7, orange

I've setup Orange and tried to execute [this code](http://blog.biolab.si/2015/08/07/creating-a-new-data-table-in-orange-through-python/) in PythonWin

And got error on 2nd line

Was my setup of Orange incomplete or it's something else?

```
>>> from Orange.data import *
>>> color = DiscreteVariable("color", values=["orange", "green", "yellow"])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'DiscreteVariable' is not defined
```

Comment: And this is why you shouldn't use wildcard imports... Do `from Orange import data` then `print dir(data)` to see what you *are* getting.

Comment: @jonrsharpe  I'm getting       ['Domain', 'Instance', 'StringValue', 'Table', 'Value', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', 'continuization', 'core', 'discretization', 'filter', 'imputation', 'io', 'outliers', 'preprocess', 'sample', 'utils']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the guy in the blog post is doing, or maybe there are some other steps that he explained in previous blog posts, but this code 'as is' is not going to work.

I searched [the source code](https://github.com/biolab/orange/tree/master/Orange) for Orange, and `DiscreteVariable` isn't mentioned *anywhere*, not as class, not as regular word, nothing.

What I did find however is

```
Discrete = core.EnumVariable
```

in [`Orange/feature/__init__.py`](https://github.com/biolab/orange/blob/master/Orange/feature/__init__.py). As you can see this points to core.EnumVariable, which appears, looking at [`it's usage`](https://github.com/biolab/orange/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=enumvariable%28%22color%22%2C+):

```
orange.EnumVariable('color', values = ["green", "red"])\
```

to be the same as `DiscreteVariable` in your link.

So I suggest you use `from Orange.feature import Discrete` instead and use that.

Comment: I wanted to Create a new data table in Orange through Python This code worked:       core.EnumVariable('color', values = ["green", "red"])

Comment: finally I created table,  it looks like [that code](http://blog.biolab.si/2015/08/07/creating-a-new-data-table-in-orange-through-python/) was for Orange 3.0 while I'm using previous version